# Refresh Woocommerce cart fragments on specific pages only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I use a bar on my cart to show how much is needed to spend until reaching free shipping. 
So far, it works fine and it's updated nicely whenever a product is added or removed. 
The problem is that it updates on EVERY page load, when I only need it on my cart.

```
function remaining_free_shipping($limit) {
    $amount = wc()->cart->get_subtotal();
    $discount = wc()->cart->get_discount_total();
    $amount = $amount - $discount;
    $remain = $limit - $amount;
    if($remain<0) { $remain = 0; }
    return $remain;
}

function show_upsell_shipping() {
    $limit = 60000;
    $remain = remaining_free_shipping($limit);
    $perc = round(($limit-$remain)/$limit*100);
    $class = "";
    if($remain==0) {
        $perc = 100;
        $texto = "Tienes despacho GRATIS! ";
        $class = "free-ship";
    } else {
        $texto = "Te faltan " . wc_price($remain) . " para despacho gratis!";
    }
    echo "<div class='upsell-cart-shipping'>";
    echo "<p>".$texto."</p>";
    echo "<div class='bar ".$class."'>";
    echo "<div class='actual-amount' style='width:".$perc."%;'></div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
add_shortcode('show_upsell_shipping', 'show_upsell_shipping');

function update_fragments_on_cart($fragments) {
            ob_start();
            show_upsell_shipping();
            $fragments['.upsell-cart-shipping'] = ob_get_clean();
            return $fragments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'update_fragments_on_cart', 10 , 1 );
```

There's a function, `show_upsell_shipping()` that renders an HTML that shows how much is needed. 
On every refresh, there's another function that updates the fragments, `update_fragments_on_cart($fragments)`

That function is hooked:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'update_fragments_on_cart', 10 , 1 );
```

I've tried adding conditionals, like `if(is_page('cart') || is_cart())` on different parts, but apparently the fragment updater doesn't care where it's loaded.

Is there a way to reduce the load by only loading them on the cart?

Comment: @Syntax_Error it worked for me, but I pasted the code directly anyway

Comment: There is also a mistake inside your shortcode function, where you should **always return the data to be displayed** instead of echoing it… so you should use `ob_start();` before the first `echo` and `return ob_get_clean();` at the end.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec hi, thanks for the comment! could you please elaborate a bit more on how it should work? thanks!